# jQuery Mobile Load external HTML that contains an ajax call to servlet script and execute them only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have an iphone style menu for a web app POS, when i press the Clients Button it shows a page with all the clients, this is made making an ajax call to a java servlet, i use the load() function in the Main page to bring the GetCustomers.html file with a script containing the jquery code with ajax and the UL tag, when i call it (load it) in my main page it only format the UL and its respectively generated LI when i use firebug debugger with with a breakpoint in the trigger('create'); which is the last instruction inside the "pagebeforeshow" function. BUT! if i run it without debugging it does format and stylize it and show it 2 milisecons then it shows it without the jquery-mobile Listview style. im using $(this).trigger('create'); and that.listview('refresh'); and it still does not work well... any suggestions?

HERE IS THE MAIN PAGE CODE:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pagewelcomeclientes", function(){
  if( navigationInitialized == 'X'){
    var newItems = '<li data-role="list-divider">Page Options</li>';
    newItems += '<li><a href="#" class="time">Time</a></li>';
    newItems += '<li><a href="#pageclientenuevo" id="botonclientenuevo" data-icon="plus" class="clientenuevo" data-transition="fade">Agregar Cliente</a></li>';
    $(".pageOpts").empty();
    $(".pageOpts").append(newItems).listview("refresh");

    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    });  

    var loadUrl = "GetCustomers.html";
    $("#contentwelcomeclientes").load(loadUrl,function(){
    BringClientes();

    $(this).trigger('create');



    });

    var list = $('ul[data-autodividers="true"][data-sort="true"]');

    list.each(function (i, item) {

      var that = $(item);

        // Gel all the list items into an array (excluding te dividers)
        var lis = that.find('li').not('.ui-li-divider').get();

        // Sort the list items alphabetically, descending
        lis.sort(function (a, b) {
            var valA = $(a).text(),
                valB = $(b).text();
            if (valA < valB) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (valA > valB) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        // Remove all list items
        that.empty();

        // Rebuild the list with the ordered items
        $.each(lis, function (i, li) {
            that.append(li);
        });

        // Refresh/rebuild the listview
       that.listview('refresh');

    }); 

  $(this).trigger('create');

  }

});
```

HERE THE CALLED HTML:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        BringClientes = function() {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "GetCustomers",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Customers.length) {
                    $.each(data.Customers, function (i, data) {
                        var temp = null;    
                        var temp = "#cd-dropdown";
                        var temp = temp+data.msg_id;
                        var msg_data = 

                        '<li><a href="#">'+data.first_name+'</a><a href="#paginaclientesolo2"></a></li>';
                        $(msg_data).appendTo("#juntar");

                    });

                } else {
                    $("#content").html("No Results");
                }
            }
        });


    }

    </script>

  <ul   data-role="listview" 
        data-inset="true" 
        data-filter="true"
        data-autodividers="true" 
        data-sort="true" 
        data-theme="c"
        data-divider-theme="c"
        data-split-icon="grid" 
        data-split-theme="d"
        id="juntar"
        >

   </ul>
```

i think it is executing twice the script in second page, what i try to do to fix it, is naming the function and then call it only once, but it still does not work... if you need sample images i can send it by mail, this is my first question here and stacky doesn't let me upload images...

thanks in advance!! =)

Comment: Have you tried `$('#juntar').listview('refresh')` instead of `that.listview("refresh")`?

Comment: thanks OmarNew2PHP i did it, i had it with comments but i remove it, it stills do the same thing... //$("juntar").listview('refresh');

Comment: did you try `$('#juntar').listview()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets change following line  `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pagewelcomeclientes", function(){});` into as below

```
$('#pagewelcomeclientes').on('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
   // your code goes here
});
```

Also change `$(this).trigger('create');` this into `$('#pagewelcomeclientes').trigger('create');` and see what happens

If you suspect that the service is being called twice then better way to tackle is using `.html()` than using `.append()`.

You may chagne your script as below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "GetCustomers",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Customers.length) {
            var myListstring = "";
                $.each(data.Customers, function (i, data) {
                    var temp = null;    
                    var temp = "#cd-dropdown";
                    var temp = temp+data.msg_id;
                          myListstring += '<li><a href="#">'+data.first_name+'</a><a href="#paginaclientesolo2"></a></li>';
                  });
                  $("#juntar").html(myListstring);
                  $("#juntar").listview();

            } else {
                $("#content").html("No Results");
            }
        }
});
```

I would suggest that you should not complicate things using `.load()` instead u can call the service in the page itself and render the listview. Which will produce much readable code.

Hope this might get u somewhere closer to the fix.

Comment: Mayu Mayooresan thank you so much !! i gues you're right i better will put the calls into the page itself... it is getting even worse to load external, and it is because i have a menu that is always there, so if i load external pages have to be changing sizes and dealing with this kind or troubles... i'll let ya know the changes to see what you think! have a nice day!!